# How would you include newline characters in a C-shell echo command?

Tags: unix, csh

This sounds ridiculously easy, and it is with other shells.  But I can't seem to figure out how to get echo to display newlines.  For example -

```
cat myFile
```

shows the file as it actually exists, which is what I want -

```
this
is
my
file
```

whereas my script, which contains the following -

```
#!/bin/csh
set var = `cat myFile`
echo "$var"
```

removes all the newlines, which is not what I want -

```
this is my file
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding quotes around when you capture value to var, i.e. `set var = "\`cat myFile\`"` . Good luck.

Comment: Do you have access to `/bin/echo` ?

Comment: @shelter - Had tried that previously too, does not help.

Comment: @cnicutar - yes, I believe so.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in csh.  The problem isn't the `echo` command, it's the behavior of backticks in csh; the newlines never get into `$var` in the first place.

Comment: @Keith Thompson - Wow.  Just wow.  Just wondering aloud how something this basic could possibly be excluded from a language.  Anyway, alternatives would be welcome too.  What I'm ultimately trying to do here is send email who's body should contain the decently formatted contents of a log file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `echo` command, it's with csh's handling of backticks.  When you execute

```
set var = `cat myFile`
```

the newlines from `myfile` are never stored in `$var`; they're converted to spaces.  I can't think of any way to force a csh variable to include newlines read from a file, though there might be a way to do it.

sh and its derivatives do behave the way you want.  For example:

```
$ x="`printf 'foo\nbar'`"
$ echo $x
foo bar
$ echo "$x"
foo
bar
$
```

The double quotes on the assignment cause the newlines (except for the last one) to be preserved.  `echo $x` replaces the newlines with spaces, but `echo "$x"` preserves them.

Your best bet is to do something other than trying to store the contents of a file in a variable.  You said in a comment that you're trying to send an e-mail with the contents of a log file.  So feed the contents of the file directly to whatever mail command you're using.  I don't have all the details, but it might look something like this:

```
( echo this ; echo that ; echo the-other ; cat myFile ) | some-mail-command
```

Obligatory reference: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Awk to delimit each line with '\n' before the shell strings them together.

```
set var = `cat myfile | awk '{printf("%s\\n", $0)'}`
```

Assuming your echo command will interpret "\n" as a newline character, `echo ${var}` should reproduce `cat myfile` without the need for additional file access.  If the newline code is not recognized, you can try adding the -e flag to echo and/or using /bin/echo.

Comment: Works in tcsh, but not csh.

Answer (score 1):

If each line has no space, you can convert the space inside the variable into newline when needed

```
echo $var | tr " " "\n"
```

If each line has space, just convert each line break to something else before storing all lines in a variable.