# How to line break in csh script

Tags: line-breaks, csh

Hi i am trying to create a script in csh where i have to cut the name field and print it to the screen. when i do the command ( cut /etc/passwd -f5 -d":" ) by itself it works fine, all the names are in different lines, but this doesn't happen when i insert it in the script like this:

```
 #!bin/csh
 set name=`cut /etc/passwd -f5 -d":"`
 echo $name
```

They all appear one after the other. I have tried many things but none work, what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried quoting? `echo "$name"`?

Comment: yes, it shows on prompt "Word too long", basically it puts all the names into on single line i guess

Comment: If all you're doing is trying to display the results then there's no reason to store it as a variable and *then* echo it.  Simply using `cut /etc/passwd -f5 -d":"` would suffice.

Comment: because i'll have to create a page that looks loke this:  
1 "name1"       "group"    "email1"  
2 "name2"       "group"    "email2"

Comment: please don't put output specifications in comments. They should always be in the body of the question. Now we have to guess if you want the output all on one line, or more likely as numbered lines.  Use the `{}` tool at the top of the edit box on selected data to format it for legibility. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [Similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980537/how-would-you-include-newline-characters-in-a-c-shell-echo-command). Basically, the new line characters are not saved in the variable when cut is run in a csh script. So we add a newline character using awk.

echo in csh doesn't understand the \n character, even with -e option. So we can just use printf. Here's the answer:

```
#!bin/csh
set name=`cut /etc/passwd -f5 -d":" | awk '{printf("%s\\n", $0)'}`
printf "%b\n" "$name"
```

Harshad

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this -- but in my opinion it's not worth doing.

You can set a variable to a value that contains newlines, but the only way I know of to do so is to use a `set` command with a multi-line string, with backslashes to join the lines.

Here's how I did it:

```
% ( echo -n "set name = '" ; \
  cut /etc/passwd -f5 -d":" | sed 's/$/\\\/' ; echo "'" ) \
  >! tmp
% source tmp
% echo $name:q
```

I had to use `$name:q` rather than `"$name"`; when I type `echo "$name"` I get an `Unmatched ".` error.

As GigaWatt said in a comment, if all want to do is display the result, you're better off just executing the `cut` command; there's no point in saving it in a variable.

If you need to use the output of the `cut` command more than once, you can save it to a file:

```
% cut /etc/passwd -f5 -d":" > tmp
```

and use the contents of the file -- or you can just re-run the `cut` command if you don't want to create a temporary file.

It's also worth noting that the `/etc/passwd` file doesn't necessarily contain information about all the accounts on a system. Some systems supplement it with NIS or LDAP. `getent passwd` accounts for all that (unless you have an old or limited system that doesn't have the `getent` command).

Bourne-based shells, including bash, tend to handle this kind of thing more cleanly. In bash:

```
$ name="$(cut /etc/passwd -f5 -d":")"
$ echo "$name"
```

Only the final newline at the end of the very last line is lost; the `echo` command will add it.  Consider using a shell other than csh, or another scripting language like Python or Perl. csh is [widely](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) [considered](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) to be a poor scripting language.