# Linux - Is it possible to store console output in a variable but with the same format as its present in console?

Tags: linux, unix, csh

Here is my scenario:

well i use csh

1)

```
$ ls -l /corefiles/ | grep "root"
-rw-r----- 1 root  root   0 Sep 22  2014 core.3.4.
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  root  92 Sep 22  2014 ss.sh
```

2)

```
$ set textInfo=`ls -l /corefiles/ | grep "root"`
$ echo $textInfo
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 22 2014 core.3.4. -rwxr-x--- 1 root root 92 Sep 22 2014 ss.sh
```

But I need `echo $textInfo` to give output like 1).

How can I achieve this? I do not want to redirect the content into a file.
I need to store console output in a variable but with the same format as present in the console.

I need a variable which has content as below:

```
$ echo $textInfo
-rw-r----- 1 root  root   0 Sep 22  2014 core.3.4.
-rwxr-x--- 1 root  root  92 Sep 22  2014 ss.sh
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you include newline characters in a C-shell echo command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980537/how-would-you-include-newline-characters-in-a-c-shell-echo-command)

Answer (score 4):

Use `echo "$textInfo"` instead of `echo $textInfo`.  Otherwise the variable is expanded as part of the command line instead of as a string, so the newlines aren't preserved.

Comment: This did not work,, still same result,,The output is coming in same line.

Comment: its working in 'sh' But i need same cmd in 'csh' (cshell), its not working in csh

Comment: Looks like this is a csh limitation.  I just found another question asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`textInfo=$(ls -l /corefiles/ | grep "root")`

then

`echo "$textInfo"`

Comment: its working in 'sh' But i need same cmd in 'csh' (cshell), its not working in csh