# In perforce how to check if any changes were made in the entire folder, and run a post processing script only if changes were made?

Tags: perforce

I am planning to create a cron job that does a p4 sync on a specific folder every day at a certain time and does some post processing of the files in the folder.

However, before doing the post processing I would like to check if the files in the folder differ from that of the perforce repository, and only if there are changes, I'd go ahead with the post processing.

How do I integrate a p4 diff with my csh script and if there's any other elegant way to check for differences and trigger the post processing.

In summary, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
if (check for differences in <my directory>) then 
        { run my post-processing script } 
 else 
  { dont run}
```

Comment: `p4 sync -n ...` will tell you if a sync would update any files.

Comment: Right! So do I dump the result of p4 sync -n in a file and check for the keywords like "added as", then I'd know if there's something new. Is that the only way?

Comment: Now I'm confused. Do you want to run the script if any file changes, or only if file is added? `p4 sync -n ...` will report whether any files changed, were added, or deleted. For only adds, you can search for "added as". Alternatively, you can just do `p4 sync ...` and study the output -- this will perform the sync, and then you can study the results to see what changes occurred.

Comment: Ok! It could be any change, either new file addition or existing file modification. I think p4 sync -n ... or p4 sync ... works for me.
I can store the result in a variable and check if it says "File(s) up-to-date", if not then run my post processing script?

Comment: Although how do I save it in a variable?
setenv variable "exec p4 sync ..." doesn't seem to work?

Comment: [Store console output in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574245/linux-is-it-possible-to-store-console-output-in-a-variable-but-with-the-same-f).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if any new revisions have been added to the depot since your sync completed, you could run:

p4 have

in your workspace, and compare this to the output from:

p4 files

run against the corresponding depot files and/or directories.

Example:

jen@Jen: ~/workspaces/testing/depot/depot/testingjen@Jen:~/workspaces/testing/depot/depot/testing$ p4 have //depot/testing/...
//depot/testing/test#1 - /home/jen/workspaces/testing/depot/depot/testing/test

jen@Jen: ~/workspaces/testing/depot/depot/testingjen@Jen:~/workspaces/testing/depot/depot/testing$ p4 files //depot/testing/...
//depot/testing/test#2 - edit change 7445 (text)

Hope this helps,
Jen.