# How can I use a line break in a csh script "eval" statement

Tags: newline, eval, line-breaks, csh

Here is a sample script:

```
#!/bin/csh
set cmd="echo hello\ndude"
eval $cmd
```

Output:

```
hellondude
```

Desired output:

```
hello
dude
```

The `eval` statement doesn't process the line break properly.

How can I make this work like I want?

Comment: `\n` doesn't have meaning inside regular strings.

Comment: ...and, frankly, if it *had* processed the line break properly, it would be echo'ing `hello`, followed by giving you a command-not-found error unless you have an executable named `dude`.

Comment: Also, csh is a very, **very** poorly-designed shell; there's a lot it simply doesn't allow you to do. For a closely related question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980537/how-would-you-include-newline-characters-in-a-c-shell-echo-command

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I actually want it to perform as your second comment suggests.  I am trying to issue a command that will hang unless you hit enter after executing it.  I would like to trick the shell into thinking the command was issued and then enter was pressed.

Comment: If I could just add a new line to the end of the command it should theoretically work but `eval` doesn't seem to like that.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you said..
"I am trying to issue a command that will hang unless you hit enter after executing it."

So based on that and what I can gather from your original post I think you just need a semicolon rather than a new line, and the second command can read a character from stdin, as follows...

```
set cmd='echo hello; set a = $<'
eval $cmd
```

This will perform the first command "echo hello" then wait input from the keyboard, or "hang" as you mentioned.

Comment: The problem is I don't want it to wait for user input.  I want it to act as if the user hit enter automatically.

Comment: In that case just use a semicolon... set cmd="echo hello;dude"